# How to send value of dropdown in backend in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am using Spring + AngularJS. How to send value of dropdown in backend in angularjs?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select  ng-model="algoList">
        <option ng-repeat="algo in algoList" value="{{algo}}">{{algo}}</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="applyAlgo()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-right"></span> Apply
    </button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.algoName = "";
$scope.algoList= ["DC_CleaningOperations","FilerOperation"];
$scope.applyAlgo = function() {
var response =  $http.post('/idw-dv/getAlgo', $scope.algoName);
response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    swal("Following algorithm is applied successfully. :",data,"success");
    console.log(data);
});
response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    swal( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
});
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAlgo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getAlgorithm(@RequestBody String algoName) {
    return algoName;
}
```

Comment: read more basics of angularJs and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here was the problem, the model you defined for select field is wrong and will eventually lead you to problem.

The selected value from dropdown will now be stored in algoName if you **change the ng-model to "algoName"**.

This value will now be transferred to Spring Controller as a String.

Hope this works...

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <select  ng-model="algoName">
                    <option ng-repeat="algo in algoList" value="{{algo}}">{{algo}}</option>
            </select>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="applyAlgo()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-right"></span> Apply
            </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just started angularJs, So making such silly mistakes. Thanks...:)